# Android autobuild + tests

Tags: android, unit-testing, ant

what is the easiest way to run an autobuild of android app, that includes compiling, running tests and creating an apk file (using ANT)?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **android** tool from the SDK. If you already have something that's a running project in Eclipse you just need to run the android project in the base directory of your project:

```
android update project --path .
```

And it should generate the ant build scripts needed to be able to build debug and release apks from the command line.

As for testing, there's also options to create a new test project using the android tool: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/testing/testing_otheride.html The docs in there go through details for automating and setting up test projects.

If you're looking for a way to automate all the stuff check out one of the continuous integration servers, like Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/) They're tailored to watch a software repository, automate some actions, and monitor the output.